# Google Cloud Monitoring - Alert Policies: status code : 409 - Too many concurrent edits to the project configuration

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create alert policies for Kubernetes Clusters in Google Cloud Platform. The following is the sample code.

```
service, err := monitoring.NewService(context.Background())
if err != nil {
    log.Panicln(err)
    return
}

mqlCondition := &monitoring.MonitoringQueryLanguageCondition{
    Duration: "60s",
    Query: `fetch k8s_pod
            | metric 'kubernetes.io/pod/volume/utilization'
            | filter
                (resource.cluster_name == 'test'
                 && resource.pod_name =~ 'server.*')
                && (metric.volume_name =~ 'dat.*')
            | align mean_aligner()
            | window 10m
            | condition value.utilization > 0.001 '10^2.%'
            `,
    Trigger: &monitoring.Trigger{
        Count: 1,
    },
}
condition := monitoring.Condition{
    DisplayName:                      "MQL-based Condition",
    ConditionMonitoringQueryLanguage: mqlCondition,
}
alertpolicy := &monitoring.AlertPolicy{
    DisplayName:          "Prakash1",
    Combiner:             "OR",
    Conditions:           []*monitoring.Condition{&condition},
    NotificationChannels: []string{"projects/abc-app/notificationChannels/16000000099515524778"},
    
}
p, err := service.Projects.AlertPolicies.Create("projects/abc-app", alertpolicy).Context(context.Background()).Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Panicln(err)
    return
}
```

**When I create two or more alert policies concurrently**, I get the following error:

```
"googleapi: Error 409: Too many concurrent edits to the project configuration. Please try again., aborted"
```

Can you please tell me how I can resolve this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, you can't add policies concurrently. I would suggest you to generate in parallel the creation requests and serialize the actual API call. You can achieve this with buffered channels and multiple go routines. For example:

```
var(
  backlogSize = 3 //change as per your needs
  requests = make(chan *monitoring.AlertPolicy, backlogSize)
)
func createPolicies(){
  ...
  go func(){
     //init the service
     ...
     for policy := range requests {
       p, err := service.Projects.AlertPolicies.Create("projects/abc-app", policy).Context(context.Background()).Do()
       if err != nil {
         log.Println(err)
       }
     }
  }()
  go func(){
     newPolicy := &monitoring.AlertPolicy
     //fill policy
     ...
     requests <- newPolicy 
  }()
  ...
  //wait for completion and close requests channel
}
```

Another solution would be to retry with exponential backoff + jitter each failed concurrent request